# How to find list view checkbox checked count in android

Tags: android

I am placed check box in custom list view I have to take selected check box value  can anybody tell how to do

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

use OnCheckedChangeListener in ur adapter and maintain avariable which will tracks ur checked counter.

if(ischecked)
  counter++;
else c
   counter--;

it helps u...

Answer (score 0):

save the value of `checkbox` when it is checked ..for this use `getView()` method of your adapter..